# Is it possible to initialize variables outside of a class?

Tags: java, variables

EDIT: is it possible or usefull to initialise variables outside of a class? 
for example if I have a code like this:

```
static int example = 1;

public class test {

public static void main(String []args) {
System.out.println("I have " + example + " question!");
}
```

or is it more usefull to do it just like that:

```
public class test {
static int example = 1;

public static void main(String []args) {
System.out.println("I have " + example + " question!");
}
```

if both ways are possible, what are the differences?
thank you in advance

Comment: Your 1st example won't compile.

Comment: Have you tried?

Comment: Both examples won't compile

Comment: Neither of these work. The former is a syntax error and the latter refers to an instance variable from a static method. Oh, and welcome to StackOverflow. Be sure to read the help center, where it says that you should always make an attempt to try things out before posting. It is fine to ask why these things do not work, rather than asking whether they work or not, which you should try first. Cheers.

Comment: Please read (and follow) the
[Java Naming Conventions](/www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html)

Comment: thanks alot. you are right... my bad

Answer (score 0):

No neither of your snippets will work. The first will not work because Java does not have global variables and the second won't work because main is static and static methods cannot access class variables that aren't static

Answer (score 0):

Because Java doesn't support global variables. Java was designed with OOPS principals in mind and as such, every variable in Java is either local or a member of a class.

So you cannot declare variables outside of class.

Answer (score -3):

In Java, declaring variable outside the class declaration is not allowed and will result to compilation error.

You must go with the second code snippet that you've posted. Below is the edited version of your code to make it work:

```
public class test {
   private static int example = 1;

   public static void main(String []args) {
      System.out.println("I have " + example + " question!");
   }
```

}

Comment: **"class declaration is now allowed and will result to compilation error."** - Lol, I think you meant NOT allowed